# Telerik mvc grid clear filter option not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm using [telerik's MVC grid control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid) in one of my project, my code looks something like this

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
        })
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled((bool)ViewData["scrolling"]))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled((bool)ViewData["sorting"]))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]))
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Filters(filters => filters.Add(o => o.RoleId)))
)
```

The problem here is that when I click the clear filter button on the grid's column, it doesn't work, as the filter data is always posted back to the server(even on clear filter) and after clearing the filter i guess the filter is reapplied. Is this a bug in telerik control or am I doing anything wrong, are there any workaround's for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try after replacing your last line

```
.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Filters(filters => filters.Add(o => o.RoleId))
```

with just
`.Filterable()` (i.e. without any expression in it).

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything, but doesn't your answer miss the whole point, my question was why isn't the filter criteria readjusted to include the clear action before posting back to the server, at-least that was my intention, in case it was not expressed properly through my question I'm sorry,

anyway thanks for the effort